# How to listen for ESRI drawing events using ESRI drawing tools in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I am trying to make use of the built-in ArcObjects drawing tools (ie ControlsNewCircleTool) - but I need to listen for the events so I can add the drawing graphics to the database in our application.  Is there an event or way to listen for when the user has drawn a new graphic and also modified it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wiring [IGraphicsContainerEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGraphicsContainerEvents_Interface/0012000005p1000000/) to [IMap.ActiveGraphicsLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ActiveGraphicsLayer_Property/001200000m89000000/) and listen for [ElementAdded](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ElementAdded_Event/0012000005p4000000/) and [ElementUpdated](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ElementUpdated_Event/0012000005pm000000/).

Comment: thanks Kirk!

activeGraphicsLayer = (CompositeGraphicsLayer)mapControl.ActiveView.FocusMap.ActiveGraphicsLayer;
                    IGraphicsContainerEvents_Event containerEvents = (IGraphicsContainerEvents_Event)activeGraphicsLayer;
                    containerEvents.ElementAdded +=new IGraphicsContainerEvents_ElementAddedEventHandler(containerEvents_ElementAdded);
}